# jQuery - show loading image only if ajax call takes more than one second?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to show the "Loading.." animation only if the ajax call takes more than say, one second? Some of my ajax calls are pretty fast but I still see the loading icon for a fraction of a second before it disappears. May be it's just me, but I find it distracting. I don't want to remove it altogether though. Any suggestions? Here's my code -

```
    $('#loading').hide()
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

<div id="loading">
    <img alt="Loading, please wait.." src="/content/images/spinner.gif" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should put your code in a timer:

```
var $loader = $('#loading'), timer;

$loader.hide()
    .ajaxStart(function()
    {
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            $loader.show();
        },
        1000);
    })
    .ajaxStop(function()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $loader.hide();
    });
```

Comment: @Joseph I had the same question thanks for posting this solution. May I clarify the syntax - var $loader = $("#loading"), timer; is creating jquery object containing timer and selector id=loading. timer && clearTimeout(timer); why is this written like this and not simply clearTimeout(timer)? I had tried similar but only succeeded in delaying the show as opposed to only showing after x millisecs. Still not quite clear how encapsulating the global events achieves what it achieves. Could you expand?

Comment: @codepuppy - `clearTimeout` expects a timer ID as its parameter. The first time `ajaxStart` runs, `timer` will be undefined. While passing undefined to `clearTimeout` does not seem to be raising any errors, I haven't tested it enough, so I decided to rather check first if `timer` actually has an id. Nore that `timer && clearTimeout(timer);` is equivalent to `if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }`.

Comment: @JosephSilber ok yes I see that now. That is very neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a `setTimeout()`.

```
var loadingTimeout;
$('#loading').hide()
.ajaxStart(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    loadingTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
       element.show();
    }, 1e3);
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
    clearTimeout(loadingTimeout);
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: 1) You have to capture `element` as an argument. 2) Don't pass `element` since it's undefined - pass `this`. 3) this won't work in IE, since it does not allow you to pass arguments in this fashion.

Comment: @JosephSilber I'm having a bad day coding... will fix.